# Page keeps scrolling up a few inches when I try to stay at the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrollview

I have some jQuery animation where the  elements' width changes from 0% to 100% when the user scrolls to it, creating a slide effect. I gave these the class name "slideInBlock"

However, [on mobile Chrome and Firefox], I can't get the page to stay at the very bottom where the footer is. It keeps scrolling up to the div before the footer.
I tried removing various elements in the contact div, like a form, or remove the entire contact div altogether so the previous section would be the last div on the page, but nothing made a difference.

But when I remove this slideInBlock jquery code, all the sudden the page acts normally. How do I fix the jquery code, because that seems to be the culprit.

HTML:

```
<div class="sections" id="contact">
<h1 class="slideInBlock">LET'S WORK<br>TOGETHER!</h1><br>

<div>
<h5>For bookings, business questions, and other inquiries, contact me via email or fill out the form below! :)
</div>
  <h5><strong> Contact:</strong><br>hello@bluseramusica.com <br><br>

</div>



<div id="footer">
<p>By Blusera, 2019. All Rights Reserved</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sections{
  text-align:center;
  padding: 7% 8% 15%;
  margin: 0px auto;
 }
.slideInBlock{
  width:0%;
 }
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(
 function(){

 $('.slideInBlock').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        //Adjust the "200" to either have a delay or content starts fading before you reach it 
        bottom_of_window = bottom_of_window + 250;  

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'width':'100%'},800);



        }
    }); 

});
```